# Why do USB drives automount in /media/pi/?

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian, automounting

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+. At system installation of Raspbian stretch, user (sudoer) `pi` is created by default, belonging to these groups:

```
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi
```

I then added other users (some sudoers too).

Irrespective of which users are logged in, attached USB drives get automatically mounted in `/media/pi/`.

Why do they automount specifically in **that** directory?
And **not** in `/media/root/` or `/media/admin/` or `/media/helloworld/` or some other `/media/user/` directory?

Obviously this is configured somewhere. What would be the way to customize this?

Comment: This is not the case in Ubuntu. I tried with Ubuntu 19.04 and it mounts to the active user's `/media/` folder...